# Error showing category title through a relationship with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a model called "Produto", as shown in the code below.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProdutoSchema = new Schema({
  titulo: { type: String, required: true },
  preco: { type: Number, required: true },
  resumo: { type: String, required: true },
  categoria: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Categoria',
    required: true
  },
  descricao: { type: String, required: true }
});

const Produto = mongoose.model("Produtos", ProdutoSchema);

module.exports = Produto;
```

This model relates to a model "Categoria"

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CategoriaSchema = new Schema({
  titulo: { type: String, required: true }
});

const Categoria = mongoose.model("Categorias", CategoriaSchema);

module.exports = Categoria;
```

When I show the Categoria Tituto in the listing, it is not displayed. In the database, the relationship is saved as ObjectID

```
router.get('/produtos', async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    _produtos = await Produto.find({}).populate('categorias');

    res.render('admin/produtos/index', { 
      produtos: _produtos
    });   
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error)  
  }
});
```

In the view

```
produto.categoria.titulo
```

Comment: Can you describe the end result you are looking for?

Comment: I think you have a typo. try this _produtos = await Produto.find({}).populate({path: 'categoria'});

Comment: Did not work using _produtos = await Produto.find({}).populate({path: 'categoria'});